# How to segregate multiple json objects with common values into one particular object in dataweave 2.0, mule?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I am trying to create a output in which I want the common JSON objects into one object and there values accordingly;
I have a sample input like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "qty": 1,
        "plant": "p1"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "qty": 10,
        "plant": "p2"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "qty": 12,
        "plant": "p1"
    }
]
```

And the output that I want should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "qty": [
            {
                "qty": 1,
                "Plant": "p1"
            },
            {
                "qty": 10,
                "Plant": "p2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "qty": [
            {
                "qty": 12,
                "Plant": "p1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var grp = payload groupBy (item, index) -> item.id
---
grp mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
    {
        id: key,
        qty: (value map ($ - "id"))
    }
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer should also include some explanation.